# List filenames in subfolders

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to list filenames from .txt files in seperate folders to seperate columns in Excel.([sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww5t9.jpg))
I found the code below, which works nice, but does not include subfolders or placement in specific column with folder header.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFileNames()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
InitialFoldr$ = "C:\main folder dir\"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
.Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
.InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
Do While xFname$ <> ""
ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$
xRow = xRow + 1
xFname$ = Dir
Loop
End If
End With
End Sub
```

So:

```
Subfoldername1 | Subfoldername2
-------------- | --------------
Textfile1      | Textfile3 
Textfile2      | Textfile4
```

Comment: what if there are sub-subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FolderNames()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, fl1 As Object, fl2 As Object
Dim lCol As Long
Dim Files As String, sPath As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please Select a Folder"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set fl1 = fso.GetFolder(sPath)

With sht
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If .Cells(1, lCol).Value = "" Then
        .Cells(1, lCol) = sPath
    Else
        .Cells(1, lCol + 1) = sPath
    End If
End With

For Each fl2 In fl1.SubFolders
    lCol = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    sht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).Value = Right(fl2, Len(fl2) - InStrRev(fl2, "\"))
    Files = Dir(fl2 & "\*.txt")
    Do While Files <> ""
        With sht
            lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lCol + 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(lrow + 1, lCol + 1).Value = Files
        End With
        Files = Dir()
    Loop
Next
sht.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

It will list the selected path and the all folders with .txt in them. But not sub-subfolders. 
Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank so much! This does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link below.  I think this will do what you want, or at least, it will get you very close to where you need to be.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

[image]