# How to take the file name from a workbook and paste it into the columns of another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of files in a folder labelled in a specific format. For eg:

```
Part1001_SubPart01_7661273QWE
Part1001_SubPart02_8658769QWE
.....SubPart25_876827698QWE
Part1002_SubPart01_7869876WER.....
```

This is how these files are labelled, is there a way in VBA where I can get a *part* of the filename? Just the ***SubPart01/02/...*** and paste it in a column of the same/different worksheet. For e.g. a column named sub-part; so that it contains values 1 thru 25.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011836/7938503) and to cut specific parts of a string use [`InStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx), [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`Right`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxs6hz0a(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: You might also check out the split function.

Answer (score 0):

So cutting out **SubPart** would look like something around these lines:

```
Sub Cut()
Dim y As String
y = "Part1001_SubPart01_7661273QWE"
y = Right(y, Len(y) - InStr(y, "_"))
y = Left(y, InStr(y, "_") - 1)
MsgBox y
End Sub
```

Comment: The link you shared shows an example to use the InStr Left and Right function but it pulls out the address of the folder which is chosen from the browser and then prints it out on a column. Is there a way where it can go thru a selected folder and pull out the filenames (for eg ones with a .csv extension) and THEN use the InSTr and other functions to pull out only a specific part of that file name. In my case it a number which starts after the characters "_W" and ends before the character "_E"

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way using split as mentioned by Erik Westwig:

```
Sub SubPart()
    Dim sArr() As String
    sArr = Split("Part1001_SubPart01_7661273QWE", "_")
    MsgBox "The SubPart Number is : " & Right(sArr(1), 2)
End Sub
```